# How can I create an embedded ngFor inside of an ngIf statement?

Tags: angular, service, angular-material, angular9

## What I'm Trying To Do

I'm trying to create a page where there is a bunch of mat-expansion-panels that each have their own content. The content is hardcoded, but rather than having each page on it's own component, I wanted to try and make one component that gets reused and interacts with a static service in order to be scalable as more content needs to be added, or if I were to connect it to a database in the future.

## What I've Tried

What I've Tried (Variation 1)

```
<article *ngIf="code$ | async as title">
    <h1>{{title.title}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="section of title.sections | async">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    {{sTitle}}
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    {{sDesc}}
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div>
                {{sContent}}
            </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</article>
```

What I've Tried (Variation 2)

```
<article *ngIf="code$ | async as title">
    <h1>{{title.title}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="section of title.sections | async as section">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    {{sTitle}}
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    {{sDesc}}
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div>
                {{sContent}}
            </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</article>
```

What I've Tried (Variation 3)

```
<article *ngIf="code$ | async as title">
    <h1>{{title.title}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="section of title.sections | async">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    {{this.sTitle}}
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    {{this.sDesc}}
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div>
                {{this.sContent}}
            </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</article>
```

What I've Tried (Variation 4)

```
<article *ngIf="code$ | async as title">
    <h1>{{title.title}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="section of title.sections | async">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    {{this.section.sTitle}}
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    {{this.section.sDesc}}
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div>
                {{this.section.sContent}}
            </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
</article>
```

### Other Code

Snippet of Component.ts (everything is imported fine at the top)

```
code$: any;
  constructor(
    private pcts: StaticService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.code$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(params => {
        const title = params.get('slug');
        return this.pcts.pctSearch(title);
      })
    )
  }
```

Service.ts

```
export interface tSect {
  sTitle: string;
  sDesc: string;
  sContent: string;
}
export interface pct {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  sections: tSect[];
}
...
{
  id: "...",
  title: "...",
  sections: [
     {sTitle: 'Test', sDesc: 'Test', sContent: 'test'},
     {sTitle: 'Tes2t', sDesc: 'Test2', sContent: 'test2'},
  ],
},
...
pctSearch(slug: string) {
    var __FOUND = -1;
    for(var t = 0; t < this.pctarr.length; t++) {
      if(this.pctarr[t].id == slug) {
        __FOUND = t;
        return this.pctarr[__FOUND];
      }
    }
  }
```

## What Happens?

I get an error saying that the property (sContent, sTitle, or sDesc) doesn't exist on the component.

## Expected Result

The section should show a list of mat-expansion-panel(s) with the sections from the array in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the *ngFor on the mat-expansion-panel and take out the `| async` in the *ngFor, since you have already applied the pipe to the `title` in the *ngIf.

Edit:

Your pctSearch function should be:

```
pctSearch(slug: string) {
    return this.pctarr.filter(pct => pct.title === slug);
}
```

Keep in mind this will return you an array of pct's that match the slug. So if you just want the first element than just grab that first index.

Edit 2:

It was just a small error, you were missing "let" in your *ngFor. You also need to use the actual element in the loop when asking for the properties like sTitle, etc. Also in your component where you declare code$ you should also declare it's type instead of any to Observable (change any to whatever your type is).

So you're template would look like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let section of title.sections">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            {{section.sTitle}}
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            {{section.sDesc}}
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div>
        {{section.sContent}}
    </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Also in your component you should declare code$ like this:

```
code$: Observable<any>;
```

Comment: I gave that a go and it still says that sContent, sDesc, and sTitle, don't exist. I also tried the section.sWhatever and it didn't work either. Same error as before.

Comment: @HarrisonMayotte what does your pcts.pctSearch(title) method look like?

Comment: I've added the method to the bottom of the service ts file.

Comment: @HarrisonMayotte, shouldn't your if condition be, if (this.pctarr[t].title === slug) ?

Comment: I was using ID as I know that the ID field will be just one word (since it's static data) (the word(s) are "one", "two", etc.). I'll update to the strict equality operator though.

Comment: I don't understand how you are expecting that method to work if you're trying to compare and id to a title

Comment: The application has a "title" where it's a group of subsections, and the "title" has a title. The slug is the id ("one", "two", "three", etc.) and I'm comparing the slug to the id of the title if that makes any sense.

Comment: In your component when you pipe the paramMap, you're using the map operator which returns an array, my guess is that's why you're getting your error. Grab the first index of the array and you should be good. You could do something like (code$ | async)[0] as title. If you did not want to return an array, you could use the tap operator

Comment: When trying the `(code$ | async)[0]` it gave an error saying the object is "possibly null."

Comment: I take back back what I said about the map operator. If you could create a stackblitz with a simple example, I can try to help. This is a very simple issue, I'm not sure why you're running into this problem.

Comment: Will do. Standby.

Comment: Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byqmem

Comment: Check my edit on the original answer. Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks a whole ton! Where would I select the first index of that array that is returned in the search?

Comment: You can also declare a variable to "index" in the same element you declare *ngFor or you can also grab the first element using isFirst. More details here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: I meant the title itself, not the sections in the title. Would I go with `...<article *ngIf="code$[0] | async as title">...`?